# Determine relation of $x$ and $y$ from results

Tags: calculus, statistics, functions

I can't seem to determine the relation between $x$ and $y$ for this problem. All of the previous ones I have done have been doable simply by eye-balling the relation between $x$ and $y$, but here I am having a hard time configuring it.

> If $x > y$, $0 \leq x , y \leq 1 $ and $x + y = 1$ we have that
>
> 1. For $x=0.75$ and $y=0.25$ : $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}$
> 2. For $x= 0.8$ and $y=0.2$ : $f(x,y) = \frac{2}{5}$
> 3. For $x= 0.6$ and $y=0.4$ : $f(x,y) = \frac{4}{5}$
>
> What is the general function $f(x,y)$ when $x > y$, $0 \leq x , y \leq 1 $ and $x + y = 1$?

**Note**: This isn't a homework problem, this is a really small sub-problem of a stochastic problem I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your problem can be rephrased as:

If $\frac 12<x\le 1$ (and let $y=1-x$), we have...

Your function is

$$f(x)=2-2x$$

or, if you want it to be a function of $y$,

$$f(y)=2y$$

or if you really want two variables,

$$f(x,y)=1-x+y$$

Comment: I am ashamed to have not seen that. Thank you.